# refer to the calling object

Tags: javascript, html

I have some div tags and I want to make a JavaScript function that changes the background-color of the div that called the function

```
function red()
{
this.style.background="red"; // the "this" keyword doesn't refer to the calling object
}
```

And I have a lot of div tags like this

```
<div id="one" onclick="red()"></div>
<div id="two" onclick="red()"></div>
<div id="three" onclick="red()"></div>
```

Is there a way to make it happen or should I put a function for each div like this

```
function somename()
{
document.getElementById(id of the div that calls the function).style.background="red";
}
```

I don't want put alot of functions because I have too many div tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set the correct `context` for your function `red()`. You can either accomplish that with `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.apply`. Like

```
<div id="one" onclick="red.call(this)"></div>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/dFLCD/

Comment: am a beginner with java, but how does exactly my function look like ? ^^

Answer (score 2):

you just needed to pass the element that called it

```
<div id="one" onclick="red(this)"></div>

function red(element){
    element.style.background="red";
    var id = element.id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass object in function like

```
<div id="one" onclick="red(this)"></div>

 function red(element)
{
    element.style.background="red";
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, but when i used onclick="red.call(this)"
that did the job perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you attach the listener dynamically, the function will be called with the target element as *this*:

```
<script>

function showId() {
  alert(this.id);
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('foo').onclick = showId;
}

</script>

<div id="foo">foo</div>
```

You can also use *addEventListener*, it's a little more work to get it to work with *attachEvent*, but not much:

```
function showId() {
  alert(this.id);
}

function addListener(el, evt, fn) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
  } else if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent('on'+evt, function() {
      fn.call(el);
    });
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  addListener(document.getElementById('foo'), 'click', showId);
}
```

There are many versions of the *addListener* function, the above is a simple one.

Answer (score 0):

When you define event handler as HTML attribute like that:

```
<div id="one" onclick="red()"></div>
```

You have actually having an anonymous function that executes the code in the attribute. It's basically equivalent to:

```
element.onclick = function(event) {
    red();
}
```

You can clean your HTML and have a better separation from JS and HTML defines the handler directly in the JS code. Something like:

```
document.getElementById("one").onclick = red;
```

In that case `this` will be the element that fired the event. Notice that in the browser that supports standards, is better use `addEventListener`. For the records, in jQuery you will have something like:

```
$("#one").click(red);
```

Comment: *addEventListener* is "better" only in that it provides a means to efficiently add multiple listeners, however its drawback is that support is missing in a good percentage of browsers in use and so a more complex attachment strategy is required (per my answer above) . Where only one listener is required, attaching it to the appropriate event property is "better" because it is extremely robust, supported consistently by every browser in use and uses a simple property assignment rather than a separate function or method.

Comment: As I wrote, "in the browsers that supports standards". In that case `addEventListener` is a better choice. Otherwise, I would suggest to use any library that abstract the differences between standards and non standards browsers, at least for events. Using the old mechanism to set an event handler is error prone, not future proof, and limit you to write general code that you can reuse in different context and/or with 3rd party library.

Comment: "the old mechnaism...is error prone"? You mean the one that works absolutely reliably in every broswer in use (back to about NN2/IE3)? The one that works in lots of places where *addEventListener* doesn't? Attaching listeners to element properties is rock solid and as future proof as any feature can be.

Comment: "error prone" = you can accidentally override the listener added in other part of the code or from another library, and vice versa. Something that using `addEventListener` prevent. And is not "future proof" for the same reason. A really good example is `window.onload`, for instance.

Comment: Adding multiple listeners as properties is dead easy, and you can guarantee order of firing. You can't do that with addEventListener without your own event model. It's horses for courses, you can't say in general that one is "better" than the other. In the vast majority of cases, elements have only one listener per event, so there is no need for *addEventListener*. I'm not saying never use it, but to consider what you *actually* need and use what suits best.

Comment: It's not "in general". It's better only if you're working with browser that support the standars. So in that case yes, it's *a better choice*. You can't guarantee order of firing for multiple listeners especially if you use the event property, because, well, it doesn't support *multiple* listeners: so you need to introduce your own event model. The difference is: you're not going to override *anything* using `addEventListener`, if there is other code that added previously listeners for the same event. And you're sure that other code can't override your listener as well for the same reason.